# HTML dependent drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I have two drop down list in my HTML page which are taking values from my database.

I want the second dropdown menu to be dependent on the value selected on first drop down menu.

I trying to insert the value of first drop down menu to the MySQL query of the second drop down menu but wondering how it can be done.Can someone pls help me out our suggest any better way to implement this.

```
<?php
include './connection.php';
$query1 = "select * from cities";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

echo '<select name="city" id="city">';
echo '<option value="">Select...</option>';
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
echo '<option value="' . $row1['name'] . '">';
echo $row1['name'];
echo '</option>';

}
echo '</select>';

$query2 = "select * from cities_areas where city="<value selected in first dropdown      list>";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

echo '<select name="area" id="area">';
echo '<option value="">Select...</option>';
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
echo '<option value="' . $row2['area'] . '">';
echo $row2['area'];
echo '</option>';

}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: This is a common question of cascading dropdown. You need to understand that all your PHP is executed at once, you cannot have the user interact with the PHP code without the page refreshing. [Have a look at the nice tutorial here.](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

You must use forms.

```
<form name='myForm'>
 <select name="city" id="city" onChange="document.forms['myForm'].submit();">
  <!--your values from DB here -->
 </select>
</form>
```

Now, in your PHP code write something like (a):

```
$query2 = "select * from cities_areas where city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['city'])."'";
```

---

(a) Please, note, that mysql_real_escape_string is a *deprecated* function and given here only for example. You should use [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.